# sudo: port: command not found after updating .bash_profile

Tags: macos, macports

I am trying to install MacPorts on my OS 10.5.8. I followed the instructions for the installation of the MacPorts-2.1.3.tar.bz2 package, and after adding the following lines to my `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:opt/local/bin
export PATH

PATH=$PATH:opt/local/sbin
export PATH
```

I still got the following error when I tried to execute the the `sudo port -v selfupdate` command:

```
sudo: port: command not found
```

After investigating a similar post about the same error, I still am confused. Is it because I have my new path statements in the my `.bash_profile` and not in `.profile` or is it also because I forget the `MANPATH` environment variable?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a leading backslash: `/opt/local` - not `opt/local`

The automated annotations from a MacPorts install always *prepended* the following directories for me: `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`, in `.profile`.

i.e., the port binaries should take precedence over the system, or whatever else you have in your current `PATH`.

Comment: thank you. my `.profile` now looks like yours but I am still getting the same error. I have complicated the problem, perhaps because in the interim I installed MacPorts again but with the .dmg version. Do you know if the dmg version has a different path port binaries?

Comment: Never mind, each time I updated my profile i did the following: `vi .profile` made the changes, save the file, but never did `source .profile<ent>` which actually executed the new changes.